# WIFI printing on Android

Tags: android, printing, wifi

Is there an easy way to do the printing in Android via Wi-Fi connection?

I'm asking this because newer mobile printers are mostly built to support only Wi-Fi printing (BLE only using to discover mobile/printer connection). Also, many printers only print with their parent apps from Gplay.

https://developer.android.com/training/printing/index.html didn't yet try. Anyone?

Asking this because all the other topics are ages old.

Comment: Why does it matter tyat the printer is connected through WiFi (versus Bluetooth/BLE, WiFi Direct, or a USB-to-parallel printer connection)? Are you trying to write a print driver?

Comment: No, just send a text (full receipt in A4 format) to the printer. Because I've managed to implement it with Zebra SDK for Bluetooth connection. Is there anything I should be aware off when sending via Wi-Fi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, printing in Android has nothing to do with a particular connection type between the Android device and the printer. That is because those details are hidden behind some API, such as:

- the [native Android printing framework](https://developer.android.com/training/printing/index.html)
- Google Cloud Print
- the Zebra SDK that you used

The only time when a particular connection type (WiFi vs. WiFiDirect vs. Bluetooth/BLE vs. lots of tiny carrier pigeons) will matter is if you are trying to bypass all of that and talk to the printer directly.

> Is there anything I should be aware off when sending via Wi-Fi?

Assuming that you are looking to print directly to the printer:

- The printer manufacturer may not support third-party developers working directly with the printer
- The printer manufacturer may not have any documentation for the protocols that they use
- The printer manufacturer may not be using standard protocols
- Etc.

Generally speaking, you want to print by using whatever the printer manufacturer recommends for printing from Android.